# How can I get Serial.print to print a variable thats a char?

Tags: serial, print

I'm trying to write a function as part of my code, and the function basically has to write the name of a parameter, but I can't get it to print properly to the screen. Here is what I've got:

```
void dataprint(char parameterName, float dataNum, char unitName);
{
 Serial.print(",");
 Serial.print(parameterName);
 Serial.print(",");
 Serial.print(dataNum);
 Serial.print(",");
 Serial.print(unitName);
}
```

In the actual program part I have something like this:

```
char temp = "temperature";
float t = tempsensor.readTempC(); // just some number that comes from sensor
char unit = "C";
dataprint(temp,t,unit);
```

Right now in the serial monitor I get a question mark or something like that instead of the name I have saved in parameterName or unitName. I want this function to print the same way something like this would show up:

```
Serial.print(",");
Serial.print("temperature");
Serial.print(",");
Serial.print(c);
Serial.print(",");
Serial.print("C");
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `char unit = "C";` won't compile, and that's quite important to your question. Could you edit the question with the code you really have please?

Comment: @MarkSmith Funny thing with that is: it'll compile. (@ Arduino IDE 1.8.1)

Comment: @KIIV Just tested it, and so it does. That's mad. Confirmed not compile on the (older) version I was using!

Answer (score 3):

To make your code work, you must use character array pointers. A "char" holds only one character, while "char*" can point to a string.

```
char foo = 'a';
char *bar = "string with lots of stuff.";
```

So the full code to implement your example is:

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void dataprint(char *parameterName, float dataNum, char *unitName)
{
  Serial.print(parameterName);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(dataNum);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.println(unitName);
}

void loop() {
  char *temp = "temperature";
  float t = 123.4;
  char *unit = "C";
  dataprint(temp,t,unit);

  while(1)
  {
    //do nothing
  }
}
```

Which prints the following to the serial port:

```
temperature,123.40,C
```

Comment: It works, but it's bad C++: `warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’`. This means you should replace every `char *` with `const char *`.